# Download big files with authentication token using streams

Tags: download, stream, cross-browser, polyfills

I am trying to download files using `fetch`, because it needs authentication in its header. The problem was that when the file is too big, the user had to wait a lot of time to get any feedback from the browser, until it said that the file is actually downloaded, so I tried to streamsaver, to make appear the "download" menu in the browser, while being downloaded.

> [image]

While it works on Chrome, the problem I am facing now is that Firefox does not seem to support the Stream API, so I tried to use a polyfill, but it does not seem to work.

```js
import { createWriteStream, supported } from 'streamsaver';
import { WritableStream } from 'web-streams-polyfill/ponyfill/es6';

const downloadWithToken = async (url, name) => {

    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    const authorization = 'Bearer ' + token;
    const headers = new Headers({ authorization });
    const options = { headers };

    let response = await fetch(url, options)

    if (!supported) {
        window.WritableStream = WritableStream;
    }
    const filestream = createWriteStream(name);
    const writer = filestream.getWriter();

    if (response.body.pipeTo) {
        writer.releaseLock();
        return response.body.pipeTo(filestream);
    }

    const reader = response.body.getReader();

    const pump = () =>
        reader
            .read()
            .then(({ value, done }) => (done ? writer.close() : writer.write(value).then(pump)));

    pump();
};
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem ([how to consume the stream from Axios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58609130/how-to-consume-the-download-stream-from-axios-using-streamsaver-js)). This is how I solved it:

```js
import { WritableStream } from 'web-streams-polyfill/ponyfill';
import streamSaver from 'streamsaver';

// If the WritableStream is not available (Firefox, Safari), take it from the ponyfill
if (!window.WritableStream) {
    streamSaver.WritableStream = WritableStream;
}

const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream(fileName);

// The rest stays more or less the same, depends on the use case. For more detail in this section, refer to this example:
// https://jimmywarting.github.io/StreamSaver.js/examples/fetch.html
```

The idea is to check if `window.WritableStream` is available in current browser or not. If not, assign the `WritableStream` from `ponyfill` directly to `streamSaver.WritableStream` property.

Tested on Google Chrome 78, Firefox 70, Safari 13; [web-streams-polyfill 2.0.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-streams-polyfill/v/2.0.5), and [StreamSaver.js 2.0.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamsaver/v/2.0.3)