# How to consume the download stream from Axios using StreamSaver.js?

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, vue.js, axios, streaming

On my server-side, which is built using Spring Boot framework, it returns a stream which looks like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<StreamingResponseBody> downloadFiles(@RequestBody DownloadRequest payload) {

    // Set proper header
    String contentDisposition = "attachment;filename=download.zip";

    // Build the response stream
    StreamingResponseBody stream = outputStream -> {
        archiveManagerService.downloadFiles(payload.getArchiveId(), payload.getFiles(), outputStream);
    };

    return ResponseEntity.ok()
            .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/zip"))
            .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, contentDisposition)
            .body(stream);
}
```

It works fine for me. I can download the file using Postman. Now, I need to call this endpoint **from the client-side** using [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios). After some searches, I found a library called [StreamSaver.js](https://github.com/jimmywarting/StreamSaver.js). This library works fine with [fetch](https://jimmywarting.github.io/StreamSaver.js/examples/fetch.html) (view source to see the example code). However, I don't know how to use it with Axios.

Currently, my code looks like this (I use Vuejs):

```
import axios from 'axios';
import streamSaver from 'streamsaver';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: '<my_base_url>',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});

instance.post('/download', postData, {
    responseType: 'stream'
})
.then(response => {
    // What should I put here? These lines below don't work
    const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream('download.zip');
    response.data.pipe(fileStream);
});
```

I got an error saying that

> response.data.pipe is not a function

So, how can I consume the stream from the client-side with Axios? Or maybe there is a better solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As pointed out by [schnaidar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58658350/1814420), at the moment, Axios cannot consume a stream from the client-side ([issue 479](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/479)).

So, the solution is to use the `fetch` API instead. However, this is an experimental feature and **not compatible with all browsers**. According to my test, it works fine on Google Chrome but not with Firefox or Safari. To overcome this problem, I use another Javascript library called `web-streams-polyfill`.

Below is my code (only important parts included):

```js
import { WritableStream } from 'web-streams-polyfill/ponyfill';
import streamSaver from 'streamsaver';

fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
})
.then(response => {

    let contentDisposition = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition');
    let fileName = contentDisposition.substring(contentDisposition.lastIndexOf('=') + 1);

    // These code section is adapted from an example of the StreamSaver.js
    // https://jimmywarting.github.io/StreamSaver.js/examples/fetch.html

    // If the WritableStream is not available (Firefox, Safari), take it from the ponyfill
    if (!window.WritableStream) {
        streamSaver.WritableStream = WritableStream;
        window.WritableStream = WritableStream;
    }

    const fileStream = streamSaver.createWriteStream(fileName);
    const readableStream = response.body;

    // More optimized
    if (readableStream.pipeTo) {
        return readableStream.pipeTo(fileStream);
    }

    window.writer = fileStream.getWriter();

    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    const pump = () => reader.read()
        .then(res => res.done
            ? writer.close()
            : writer.write(res.value).then(pump));

    pump();
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
});;
```

The idea is to check if `window.WritableStream` is available in the current browser or not. If not, assign the `WritableStream` from `ponyfill` directly to `streamSaver.WritableStream` property.

Tested on Google Chrome 78, Firefox 70, Safari 13; [web-streams-polyfill 2.0.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-streams-polyfill/v/2.0.5), and [StreamSaver.js 2.0.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamsaver/v/2.0.3)

Answer (score 3):

So as it seems the streaming function is not implemented for the browser (see also https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/479). So you might have to use fetch like in the example.