# Streaming zip to browser doesn't work, but works in Postman

Tags: express, axios, stream

I'm using the following [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-zip) to download a ZIP file directly in the browser. For that I'm using following code in the frontend:

```
      await this.$axios
        .get(
          `/inspections/defects/download/${this.$route.params.uuid}`, {
              responseType: 'arraybuffer' // This is the problem
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(
            new Blob([response.data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' })
          );
          const link = document.createElement('a');
          link.href = url;
          link.setAttribute('download', 'file.zip');
          document.body.appendChild(link);
          link.click();
        });
```

And from the backend I just directly use

```
app.get('/download/:uuid', (req, res) => {
  // get filename from db, but it's 99,9% the same as the example provided in the readme of the npm package.

  s3Zip
    .archive({ region: region, bucket: bucket }, '', 'abc.jpg')
    .pipe(res)
})
```

When I try to "send & download" via postman, it works perfectly, it downloads a zip with the image in it for around 5MB which is correct.

Now when I try to download it via the axios code, I get either

[image: error 1]

Or

[image: error 2]

After some research I always come to the same solution and that is to set the responseType and it seems to work for everyone. However, if I try to do that I get the following console errors, and I can't find any related issues when I google it:

[image: console error]

I've also tried with different content types, but can't seem to get my head around it. Especially because it works in Postman.

Related issue, but that was fixed by using arraybuffer:
https://github.com/orangewise/s3-zip/issues/45

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/58696592 axios doesn't support file streaming right now. I used native fetch and now it works fine.

The dozens of examples on how to do it with axios are pretty misleading.